# Вывести 5 рубрик, а остальные скрыть

Tags: jquery, javascript, wordpress

Вывожу рубрики на сайт, как сделать чтобы вывелось 5 рубрик а остальные скрылись?
Ну не совсем скрывались, а появлялась стрелочка, при нажатии открываются следующие рубрики. Шаблон поставил на `wordpress`, помогите со скриптом. Может какой плагин есть для вордпреса?

Comment: так ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ugRhp/

Comment: да это понятно, не по теме ответили. Как делается в вордпрес, вот создаю меню, ставлю ссылки меню на 2 уровень, а у меня не скрываются страницы 2 уровня, светятся, почему?

Comment: в смысле меню сразу раскрытое ? наверное у вас в css проблема.